# How to renew aws reserved instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services

One of my reserved instance is about to expire in near futre.

I'd like to buy the reserved plan for the instance
(I'm not planning to run 2 such instances at the same time)
I just want to extend the reserved period if it makes sense.

How do I do that?
feels like this might be very good fit for stackoverflow, please let me know if there's a better qna site for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Learn How to Renew an EC2 Reserved Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/renew-ri/):

> You can queue your Reserved Instance purchases for a specific date and time in the future. To renew your EC2 RI automatically, you can queue an RI purchase for the date and time that your existing RI expires. On the scheduled date and time, AWS automatically purchases the RI for you using your account's default payment method.

Before renewing, I would suggest you also consider [AWS Savings Plans](https://aws.amazon.com/savingsplans/), which are more flexible than Reserved Instances. Also, consider whether you want a 1-year term or a 3-year term and, for RIs, whether it is Zonal or Regional.

Comment: oh thanks for answer and useful tips. I'll definately check out savings plan.. although it is kinda vague what the difference is between RI and savings plan..